# Assign port to process/application in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a POS Terminal server in a restaurant that uses an old POS software. This software has a built in webserver running on port 80. I have recently installed a VOIP PBX server software onto the same machine and for some reason, it runs into problems when another application is assigned to port 80. Is there a way to assign a port to a specific process/application in windows 7? Do they get assigned based on order opened (ie. If I was to run the PBX Server software first, then the POS server software or vice versa?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the configuration files of the POS software to see if the port 80 can be changed to another number. If not, I am afraid to say that you can not change the Port with external tools since the port number is set within the binary code.